# Where can I buy a Stereo audio to 3.5mm adapter?

Tags: adapter, stereo, 3.5mm

I need a stereo (6.33mm) to PC audio (3.5mm) adapter, and I'd like it to have an inch or two of cable so that yanking the connector doesn't break the audio port the 3.5mm is plugged into.

I used to own one of these, but I lost the adapter. Where can I buy something like this online? I can only find solid adapters or 25' cables.

Comment: this isn't a shopping site.  asking *what* to buy for a certain purpose is one thing; asking *where* to buy is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: for historic reasons its a quarter inch cable, not a 6.3mm cable

Comment: @quack quixote: It's only not a shopping site historically. The users define the site, and right now I think superuser is failing to pull critical mass. All PC questions are by their nature extraordinarily timely. Even changing the screen resolution isn't a solution that will last a year for a linux distribution, for example. It's wrong to close this topic, and you're actively hurting the site. I'll continue to use superuser as I please, and clearly the number of replies and votes agrees with my usage.

Comment: PC tech does change often, yes.  but if next year you search for how to change the screen resolution on ubuntu 9.04, and find an answer here posted last year, it will still be a useful answer.  (it won't be valid for ubuntu 12.10, no.)  that is not true for prices and *may* not be true for stores.  that's the short version of this policy; if you'd like to discuss this further please post on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot go wrong with buying from [Monoprice](http://www.monoprice.com).  Top notch quality and customer service every time I've used them.  Some people think their cables roll out of the same factories as name brand minus the labels.

See this [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/120410/where-to-buy-longer-pc-cables-online/120414#120414).

Specifically you would be interested in this [cable](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10218&cs_id=1021802&p_id=5575&seq=1&format=2) (M/M) or [this one](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10218&cs_id=1021808&p_id=5586&seq=1&format=2) (M/F) and this [adapter](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10401&cs_id=1040109&p_id=682&seq=1&format=2).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is something [like this](http://www.shoppingbank.com/sb/pia/d/soundlab+35mm+stereo+jack+extension+coiled+with+jack+multiple+adapters/pid/10327013?afid=105749) suitable for you?:

[image]

Or [this](http://cgi.ebay.com.my/Headphone-Adapter-Female-1-4-6-3-mm-to-Male-1-8-in-3-5_W0QQitemZ200377220040QQcmdZViewItemQQptZLH_DefaultDomain_0?hash=item2ea769bbc8) may be the one you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: Even if that was 6.33mm to 3.5mm, it's a lot longer than I need. I should have mentioned that I also need female -> male.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, but DAMN it's expensive for an adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Several devices/adapters here

[Startech Adapters](http://www.startech.com/ToolsGuides/ConXitResult.aspx?itematr=CONXITLEFT:3.5%20mm%20Stereo%20Audio,CONXITRIGHT:Stereo%20Audio)

Answer (score 0):

Monoprice is always good, as user26453 mentioned. If you're looking for it right now (walk in and buy as opposed to shipping) RadioShack is usually good for all those little bobs and bits.